# What is a coordinate-free formulation of deformation theory?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

For example how are stress, strain and shear tensors described invariantly, without any coordinates, purely in a geometric manner?

A formulation that avoids indices coordinates and matrices, even in practical calculations.

Comment: Have you looked at the brief description of [the tensor form of the linear elasticity equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Direct_tensor_form) on Wikipedia?

Comment: Yea but  it's too brief, and it doesn't show any concrete examples, without Cartesian or other coordinates.

Comment: You cannot avoid coordinates and indices in practical (physics) calculations.

Comment: I'm not looking for opinions here

Comment: @Ezio It's "too brief" because that's all there is to it, and there aren't any examples because for almost all practical purposes you need a definite coordinate system. How would you propose to define the stress-strain relationship for a general anisotropic material, unless you have some way to talk about the orientation of the material at different points in space, for example - and that is going to involve defining some basis vectors, which is the same thing as a coordinate system.

Comment: I think what it means to be 'coordinate free' is to be able to write and do things without the use of a favoured coordinate. So if the thing you are working on is described by M, you could do things to it in any arbitrary coordinate and still get the same result. You could say M is the one true thing, what ancient Greeks call the ideal object containing all the information of the object you are studying, but to learn anything you need to choose a basis and measure. Like how 1 inch is 2.54 cm but the distance is the same, just that there's no other way to describe it except using units.

Comment: Say you had a random arrow appear in front of you. You can push the arrow, spin it, shrink it and what not but it will always be straight. You could walk around it or away. The arrow could be pointing at you or to your right depending on your position or what you did to it. But at the end of the day to figure out what the heck you've actually done to the darn thing is to take a out a measuring stick, a protractor and a set square and actually measure it relative to your position.

Comment: No That's Not At All What I Mean By Coordinate free

Comment: As I described I mean manifestly free, that is completely coordinateless

Comment: @alphzero As Far As I Know physics is based on geometric relations between geometric objects. I think you have mixed up geometry and geography..

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend looking at works of W. Noll, C. Truesdell and collaborators. They have been working on the mathematical foundations for continuous mechanics since 1950-s producing several textbooks & monographs with most notable being *The non-linear field theories of mechanics* by C. Truesdell & W. Noll.

For more modern exposition see the paper:

- Noll, W., & Seguin, B. (2010). *Basic concepts of thermomechanics*. Journal of Elasticity, 101(2), 121-151, [doi:10.1007/s10659-010-9253-x](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10659-010-9253-x), [free pdf](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ewn0g/BCTM+.pdf).

From the introduction:

> This paper is intended to serve as a model for the first few chapters of future textbooks on continuum mechanics and continuum thermomechanics.  It may be considered an update of the paper *Lectures on  the Foundations  of  Continuum  Mechanics  and  Thermodynamics* [N2] by one of us (W.N.), published in 1973,and an elaboration of topics treated in Part 3, entitled *Updating the Non-Linear Field Theories of Mechanics*, of the booklet [FC] by W.N.${}^1$.

> The present paper differs from most existing textbooks on the subject in several important respects:
>
> 1. It uses the mathematical infrastructure based on sets,  mappings,  and families,  rather than the infrastructure based on variables, constants, and parameters.  (For a detailed explanation, see *The Conceptual Infrastructure of Mathematics* by W.N. [N1].)
> 2. It is completely coordinate-free and  $\mathbb{R}^n$-free when dealing with basic concepts.
> 3. It does not use a fixed physical  space.  Rather, it employs an infinite variety of frames  of  reference, each  of  which  is  a  Euclidean  space.   The  motivation  for  avoiding  physical  space  can  be  found  in  Part  1, entitled *On the Illusion of Physical Space*, of the booklet [FC]. Here, the basic laws are formulated without the use of a physical space or any external frame of reference.
> 4. It considers inertia as only one of many external forces and does not confine itself to using only inertial frames of reference.  Hence kinetic energy, which is a potential for inertial forces, does not appear separately in  the  energy  balance  equation.   In  particle  mechanics,  inertia  plays  a  fundamental  role  and  the  subject would collapse if it is neglected.  Not so in continuum mechanics, where it is often appropriate to neglect inertia, for example when analyzing the motion of toothpaste when it is extruded slowly from a tube.

See also PhD thesis [Frame-Free Thermomechanics (2010)](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ewn0g/Seguin%20Thesis.pdf) by Seguin and other papers (including those referenced in the above quote) at [Noll's webpage](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ewn0g/).

Comment: Nolls stuff is really interesting I like his approach. The link you put in seems only quasi coordinate free. It says it's c free only for basic objects.

Comment: The first link that is

Comment: The 2-nd list item of quote should be read as *It is (completely coordinate-free) and ($\mathbb{R}^n$-free when dealing with basic concepts)* : the basic concepts bit refers to $\mathbb{R}^n$ independence, at some point they do assume Euclidean spaces, theory remains coordinate-free even after that.

Comment: Euclidean space is not the same thing as Rn. I do appreciate the abstraction, but I would like to see how this formalism applies to some concrete examples. Otherwise I can't see the point of all this structure. One of the main reasons I asked for coord free is for more simplicity. For example by a tensor I simply mean some linear function of some sort of vectors.. In theory these papers seem nice,but I don't see how this apparent loss of simplicity is justified practically.

Comment: My impression is that higher level of abstraction could be used to simplify description of complicated materials: nematic liquid crystals, materials with memory etc.

Comment: That's all fine, my idea was to have a sound math formalism applied to beginning level physics

Comment: And the descriptions of otherpapers  on nolls website are a bit misleading. He says the papers on manifolfs are unusual in that the are completely coordinate free, than he goe on to define the usual charts and atlases shenanigans..

Comment: I had a look and seems that *the usual charts and atlases shenanigans*  are done in coordinate free manner.

Comment: Hmm I'll check it out, but seems kind of impossible..

Answer (score 3):

The infinitessimal strain tensor is defined by $\textstyle{\frac 12} {\mathcal L}_{\boldsymbol \eta} {\bf g}$ where ${\bf g}$ is the usual metric of our 3-d euclidean world. Here ${\mathcal L}_{\boldsymbol \eta}$ is the Lie derivative with respect to the displacement vector field $ {\boldsymbol \eta}$.  For large  displacements that take a point ${\bf r}$ to $\phi({\bf r})$ we define the finite strain as $\textstyle{\frac 12}( \phi^*({\bf g})-{\bf g})$. Here $\phi^*{\bf g}({\bf x},{\bf y})= {\bf g}(\phi_*({\bf x}),\phi_*({\bf y}))$. In other words take two *small* displacements ${\bf x}$, ${
\bf y}$ in the undeformed material and take their inner product. Now deform the material so that the displacement vectors get moved (possibly a long way) and stretched and rotated to (still small) displacements $\phi_*({\bf x})$ and $\phi_*({\bf y})$. Take their new inner product (in our  ambiant 3-space). The difference between the original inner product and the one of the deformed vectors defines the finite strain tensor ${\bf e}$ evaluated on ${\bf x},{\bf y}$ .  None of the these concepts need a coordinate system.

Comment: OK this makes sense. Something along the lines of what I had in mind. So let's say than for example cauch stress tensor. It would be some linear  function that would take in vectors(functions, displacements). What are some practical or real world examples of this. Without having to resort to coordinates?